# JPA @Converter on AutoGenerated primary key int to String Hibernate Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I've this issue , my `id` is an int in the data base just to be clear . and I'm using a Converter as follows :

```
@JsonView(Views.Public.class)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "INC_IDTECHX", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "INC_IDTECHX", sequenceName = "INC_X", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "IDTECHX", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 0)
@Convert(converter = IntConverter.class)
private String idtechX;
```

I'm using this to solve an issue where I needed to build a creteria:

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(criteria.getIdtechX())) {
String like = criteria.getIdtechX().replace("*", "%");
predicates.add(cb.like(root.get("idtechX"), like));
}
```

this is why I made the converter in the fisrt place so I can make a search with % in my db , but this made it impossible to creat new Object because Hibernate give me this error

> Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String] with root cause org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data type for ids : java.lang.String

so I don't see a solution to make this work as intended . thanks for the help

Comment: In my opinion, you should rework the criteria and use a simple generated int value as ID

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm using criteriaBuilding and the like works only on Strings because some daba bases support the % on int ( like Oracle ) and some dont so they made impossible to make .

Comment: If you search by ID, you should know the exact value, else you can search for an ID range

Comment: This is to add a functionality where I've a website and if the user want to see all the items which have an id = 1245% and theese kinda of option

Comment: I do understand what you want to do with it, but yet ID should be hold simple. If you really want to do it that way, you can make it much easier by having an extra column which is stored as `varchar` and to whcih you assign the value of the ID. Then you can filter on the extra column while not needing the converter and so on

Comment: @XtremeBaumer that's exactly what I was doing atm but I find it a bit ugly as a solution .

Comment: It is the cleanest solution you can do

Comment: If you want to do a query on a `int` DB column, using like you can always use CAST (in JPQL/Criteria). That way no need for extra columns